# Create column name for 2 customers in one account SQL

Tags: sql, string, db2, aggregate-functions

I have data about customers linked to there accounts. In one account we can have one or more customers, i would like to create the "Account Name" column based on the names of customers those compose the account, like this :

The original data :

| Account ID | Customer ID | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 68959 | 121048 | ROQUES THIERRY |
| 68959 | 121049 | CAPO SYLVIE |
| 76280 | 121276 | CORSEAUX PHILIPPE |
| 76280 | 121277 | ARRIAT SANDRINE |
| 56800 | 121623 | PERSONNA DIDIER |
| 79551 | 121771 | TRUQUEZ PHILIPPE |
| 79551 | 121772 | SLUGACZ KAREN |
| 81646 | 122081 | MOREAUX FABIEN |

After creation of the Account name based on the customers those compose the account :

| Account ID | Customer ID | Name | Account Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 68959 | 121048 | ROQUES THIERRY | ROQUES THIERRY&CAPO SYLVIE |
| 68959 | 121049 | CAPO SYLVIE | ROQUES THIERRY&CAPO SYLVIE |
| 76280 | 121276 | CORSEAUX PHILIPPE | CORSEAUX PHILIPPE&ARRIAT SANDRINE |
| 76280 | 121277 | ARRIAT SANDRINE | CORSEAUX PHILIPPE&ARRIAT SANDRINE |
| 56800 | 121623 | PERSONNA DIDIER | PERSONNA DIDIER |
| 79551 | 121771 | TRUQUEZ PHILIPPE | TRUQUEZ PHILIPPE&SLUGACZ KAREN |
| 79551 | 121772 | SLUGACZ KAREN | TRUQUEZ PHILIPPE&SLUGACZ KAREN |
| 81646 | 122081 | MOREAUX FABIEN | MOREAUX FABIEN |

This must be realize by the SQL statement, wath you recommend me to do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use string aggregation function `listagg()`. I am unsure whether DB2 supports it as a window function:

```
select t.*,
    listagg(name, ' & ') within group(order by customerid) over(partition by accountid) as accountnames
from mytable t
```

If not, you can use a correlated subquery instead:

```
select t.*,
    (
        select listagg(t1.name, ' & ') within group(order by t1.customerid) 
        from mytable t1 
        where t1.accountid = t.accountid
    ) as accountnames
from mytable t
```

Comment: Db2 does allow LISTAGG with OLAP windowing. Only "ARRAY_AGG, CUME_DIST, and PERCENT_RANK are not supported as an aggregate function in aggregation-specification (SQLSTATE 42887)." https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023461.html  ( but CUME_DIST, and PERCENT_RANK are allowed with the "ordered-OLAP-specification"